# Problem with body using html email signature in Apple Mail

Tags: html, email, responsive, signature

I am using the following html code to create a mail-signature in Apple Mail. It must show in full width, and be able to be responsive: from a Computer screen to an Ipad and/or phone screen.

The main problem it is that I can not add margin to the body text of the email, without adding also margin to the signature, left and right.

If you do not apply margins then the text gets in the beginning of the apple email window, as you might now without signature it is around 30px margin by default.

And if I add margin, then it also creates a margin on the right that force you to use the bottom bar to scroll to the right and see the text wrote there.

Tried to add margin-left and margin-right, even padding but none of the options I know have worked. I must say my html knowledge it pretty limited and basic.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

<head>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
<o:AllowPNG/>
<o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
</o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml><![endif]-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>Mail Signature</title>


<style type="text/css">
div {margin: 0; padding:0; margin: 0 !important; padding:0 !important;}
p {font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height:18px; font-family: Montserrat;}
body { width: 100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100% !important; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100% !important; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; }
.ExternalClass { width: 100% !important; }
.ExternalClass { line-height: 100% !important; }
```

## backgroundTable { margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; width: 100% !important; line-height: 100% !important; }

```
img { outline: none !important; text-decoration: none !important; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic !important; }
h1 a:active { color: red !important; }
h2 a:active { color: red !important; }
h3 a:active { color: red !important; }
h4 a:active { color: red !important; }
h5 a:active { color: red !important; }
h6 a:active { color: red !important; }
h1 a:visited { color: purple !important; }
h2 a:visited { color: purple !important; }
h3 a:visited { color: purple !important; }
h4 a:visited { color: purple !important; }
h5 a:visited { color: purple !important; }
h6 a:visited { color: purple !important; }
.ReadMsgBody {width: 100%;}
a {outline:none;}
.appleaddress1 a {color: #363636 !important; text-decoration: none;}
.appleaddress2 a {color: #FFFFFF !important; text-decoration: none;}    
span.yshortcuts { color:#000; background-color:none; border:none;}
span.yshortcuts:hover,
span.yshortcuts:active,
span.yshortcuts:focus {color:#000; background-color:none; border:none;}
.eoa_d7w{ width:100% !important; } .eoa_2v8{ color:#404040 !important; }


@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
.container {
    width: 1024px !important;
}
```

}

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
table.container{width: 100% !important;}
th.behave{display:block; width: 100% !important; }
td.respond{width:100% !important; }
td.btn_left{text-align: center !important;padding-left:30px;}
img{width:100% !important;height:auto !important;}  
table.respond{width:100% !important;}
td.css_btn{text-align: center !important;}
body {width: 100% !important;}
td.no-padding{padding-top: 15px !important;}
td.one-col{padding-left:0px !important;padding-right:0px !important;}
td.two-col{padding-left:15px !important;padding-right:15px !important;}
td.two-colo{padding-left:15px !important;padding-right:15px !important;}
td.two-colomn{padding-left:15px !important;padding-right:15px !important;padding-top: 6px !important;}
td.mbr_none{padding-left:0px !important;padding-right:0px !important;padding-top:5px !important;}
td.mbr_bottooms{padding-top:8px !important;}
div.special{width:100% !important;}
div.extra{white-space: wrap !important; word-wrap:break-word !important;word-break:break-all;width:100% !important;}
td.hidden{display:none; visibility: hidden; width: 0px !important; height:0px !important; font-size:0pt !important;line-height:0pt !important;}
th.hidden{display:none; visibility: hidden; width: 0px !important; height:0px !important; font-size:0pt !important;line-height:0pt !important;}
table.verywell{width:100% !important; min-width:100% !important;}
img[class="yesyesyes"] {width:100% !important;height:auto !important;min-width:100% !important;}
```

}

```
</style>

</head>

<body style="width: 100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; background: #ffffff; min-width: 100%; font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 18px;"><a style="font-family: Montserrat;">text</a>
</body>
```